# WordPress widgets how to remov the extra div tag

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

When creating a widget, WordPress puts a `<div class="typewidget">` around the widget.

**I want to remove these extra divs without editing the `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` file.**

In my theme `index.php` file, I use:

```
<ul>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
|| !dynamic_sidebar('widgetname') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Then, in the `functions.php` file:

```
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'widgetname',
'before_widget' => '<li>',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
));
```

And this shows in the site:

```html
 <ul>
    <li> 
        <div class="textwidget">
            <strong><a href="#">musica</a></strong> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sit am.</a>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A friend just helped me out and I fixed this.

After loading jQuery:

```
var cnt = $(".textwidget").contents()
$(".textwidget").replaceWith(cnt);
```

Where `.textwidget` is the class in the extra div. It varies according to each type of widget in WordPress.

Comment: In fact, this breaks some parts of the design. ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

something like the following might work.

```
var stuff_in_div = document.getElementById("typewidget").innerHTML;

stuff_in_div.parentNode.removeChild("typewidget");
```

and then if you give the < li > an id like "target", you could just shove stuff_in_div in there with:

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = stuff_in_div;
```

Does this seem reasonable?

Andy

Comment: This is cool, Andbdrew, but I need a solution working with classes instead of ids, since I'll be using this with a lot of elements, not just one per page. Do you know how to adapt your solution to this scenario?

Comment: sorry about that =D I misread your original post and thought the div had an id of "typewidget". my bad

Answer (score 0):

what about using something like:

```
var stuff = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (i=0, i<stuff.length, i++) {

    if (stuff[i].className=='typewidget') {

        var stuff_in_div = stuff[i].innerHTML;
        stuff[i].parentNode.innerHTML=stuff_in_div;

    }

}
```

seems like this might work. What do you think?

Andy